# Jquery Ajax - Managing Script Executions - Script reference missing or called twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my page am having different sections and all of them are ayncronous calls from my asp.net MVC view i return the page and i partially append the HTML to the section Div. and in my view am referring say

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/A.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/B.js"></script>
```

First time everything works perfectly.

And when user does some post back say upload in that particular section am using AJAX call and performing some operation in my controller and am returning the partial view again and appending the HTML in the section in Ajax Sucess.

But what happens in IE8 is after my view is processed am getting script undefined error that A.js , B.js reference not found."**0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error**"  and then it reaches Ajax Sucess and then processed correctly.

Does it mean my script is called twice ? How can i avoid the reference Error ?

Firefox it is working fine. Even i tried to have Ajax **DataFilter** but am getting reference Error in IE8 after view is returned and before reaching. Where exactly is my problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Avoid using JavaScript in partial views (which I assume you currently are). Put them all in the containing view instead.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie u mean in the parent view ? Index

Comment: Parent = containing, yes.

Comment: But how do i handle if in such scenarions when i need to load scripts after my partial view is loaded in document.ready ?

Comment: All scripts *potentially required for your partial views* should be specified in the parent page, so they will be loaded at initial page load. Using MVC bundles will make this more efficient (if you are worried about loading scripts you might not use). You need to provide more details of your pages and code if you need specific answers :)